# Emacs build process on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, emacs, build, compilation

I'm wondering if anyone could possibly walk me through the build process for a program after having used emacs to write the code. This is for C++ and windows 7. If I could be pointed towards a decent tutorial that would achieve the same result, that would be great as well. I've been looking around for awhile now and haven't found anything that helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, I was already able to compile code when I was using my macbook. I just don't know how to transfer my terminal skills over to command prompt.

Comment: Need to know more about your environment, but this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740836/compiling-c-programs-with-emacs-on-windows is an excellent resource.  Basically you just need to setup the M-x compile command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question and surely you've moved on.

Even so I'm going to respond in case someone else is wondering the same thing.

emacs on windows isn't special.  Emacs is just the same as it is on any other platform, and Windows C/C++ compilers work much the same as C/C++ compilers on other operating systems.

To build on emacs, regardless of platform. you can use `M-x compile`.  You then get to specify the compile command. On Windows, this could be a `cl.exe` command, or an `nmake.exe` command, or `msbuild.exe` or... `csc.exe` for C# code, or you choose.

For various buffers and modes, I run jshint, or csslint, or javac, or nmake.

There's also [a smarter-compile module](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/smarter-compile) which I use, which can generate a suggested compile command, in an intelligent manner.  IT works on Mac or Windows or Linux; Windows7 isn't special.